# LaTeX moves wrapfigure images down several pages

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I tried to make a document in which the text wraps around the images.
I have some images that do not get wrapped wich I have included by `\includegraphics` and the other one with using `wrapfigure`.

The first wrapfigure works and is at the same place as the text below (However the text is a little bit more above).
The text which should be around the next wrapfigure is also wrapped around the first one and the the picture is moved 3 pages down. On that page no other content appears.

I also tried putting a `\newpage` before and after the block with the second wrapfigure and its text but it just created a new page with only the text on it and nothing else and the picture was still moved down.

How can I make the picture and its text appear at the same place?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{letter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\signature{name}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}

\opening{Lorem ipsum,}

% corps of the letter
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est.

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{picture.jpg}

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.


\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.


\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.


\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{picture.jpg}



\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}


\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{picture.jpg}

%%%%%





\closing{Lorem}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a `\clearpage` before the 2nd wrapfigure. In your MWE this should solve the problem.

A few further Tips:

1. Use `\centering` in your wrapfigure-environment, the center-environment just addes useless space.
2. wrapfigure has an optional parameter `\begin{wrapfigure}[numberOfLinesToWrap]{position}{width}`, so you can control the amount of lines the pachages is to use for wrapping.
3. Use `\vskip-12345\baselineskip` inside the wrapfigure to control vertical placement / alignment of your picture. Please replace 1234 with a good number.